# How to ask about vacation plan

Tags: sentence-construction

1) What will you do for your vacation?

2) What are you going to do for your vacation?

3) What are you doing for your vacation?

4) What are you planning to do for your vacation?

Which questions above are correct and which one is most common in colloquial AmE?

Comment: I think this was a fair question, but there's really no answer. All of these are idiomatic and none of them sound off. I could imagine myself saying any of these, or asking in a slew of other ways, too.

Answer (score 1):

How about the below?

> Do you have plans for your vacation?

Simple and to the point.